# Form data to Json file as object

Tags: php, json, ajax, html

**My json object should look like below, which is generating on submiting the form:**

{
            "range":{
                "l1_price":
                    {"from":"0", "to":"260k", "price": "Rs .02"},
                "l2_price":
                    {"from":"260k", "to":"500k", "price": "Rs .04"},
                "l3_price":
                    {"from":"500k", "to":"1MM", "price": "Rs .007"},
                "l4_price":
                    {"from":"1MM", "to":"2MM", "price": "Rs .003"}
             }

```
    }
```

**Now the form  is like:**

```
     <form class="json_out">
        <p>
          l1_price:
          <input type="text" name="from_l1" placeholder="from range">
          <input type="text" name="to_l1" placeholder="to range">
          <input type="text" name="price_l1" placeholder="price">
        </p>
        <p>
          l2_price:
          <input type="text" name="from_l2" placeholder="from range">
          <input type="text" name="to_l2" placeholder="to range">
          <input type="text" name="price_l2" placeholder="price">
        </p>
        <p>
          l3_price:
          <input type="text" name="from_l3" placeholder="from range">
          <input type="text" name="to_l3" placeholder="to range">
          <input type="text" name="price_l3" placeholder="price">
        </p>
        <p>
          l4_price:
          <input type="text" name="from_l4" placeholder="from range">
          <input type="text" name="to_l4" placeholder="to range">
          <input type="text" name="price_l4" placeholder="price">
        </p>    
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </p>
    </form>
```

**Finally i want to send the data to data.json file on submitting the form.**

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script>
$('form.json_out').submit(function(e) {
    var values = {};
    var range = {};
    var rates = [];
    var thresholds = [];
    var result = {};
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each($('form.json_out').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        if(field.name){
            temp = {};
            name_split = field.name.split('_');
            price_lev = name_split[1] + '_' + 'price';
            val_str = name_split[0];
            val = field.value;
            temp[val_str] = val
            if (val_str == 'price'){rates.push(val)};
            if (val_str == 'to'){thresholds.push(val)};
            if (range[price_lev]){
                res = range[price_lev]
                res[val_str] = val
                range[price_lev] = res
            }
            else{
                range[price_lev] = temp;
            }
        }

    });
    result['range'] = range
    result['rates'] = rates
    result['thresholds'] = thresholds       

});
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide more info with example ?

Comment: Actually form contains 4 ranges and 4 prices for each rang3

Comment: show your actual form code.